# MFC Have enter key act as "apply" button

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

In a certain dialog I would like when the user presses the enter key for it to act as an "apply" button. So far I have at least been able to make the dialog not close upon pressing enter by overriding CWnd::PreTranslateMessage, so currently it just does nothing and  I'm not sure how to send apply command from there.

Answer (score 4):

Every dialog should have one and only one button with the [`BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which indicates to the dialog that this is the button to activate with the Enter key. Usually this is the OK button, but you can make it the Apply button if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark pointed out above the dialog manager already has all the logic built in to handle the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key by invoking the command associated with the default button. You can statically assign the [`BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx#bs_defpushbutton) style or handle the [`DM_GETDEFID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645406.aspx) message.

The former is trivially easy and the latter is fairly simple to implement. Make sure you set the *Default Button* property to *False* for all buttons on your dialog. Now add a message handler for the `DM_GETDEFID` message. There is no dedicated macro for this message so you have to use the generic handler:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialogEx)
    ...
    ON_MESSAGE(DM_GETDEFID, OnGetDefId)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The message handler is equally simple and uses the default message handler signature:

```
LRESULT CMyDialog::OnGetDefId(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return MAKELRESULT(ID_APPLY, DC_HASDEFID);
}
```

The message handler must return a value whose high-order word contains `DC_HASDEFID` and the low-order word contains the control ID.

If you navigate over the controls of the dialog you will see that the *Apply* button has the typical default button visual cue while focus is not on another command button. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while a non-button control has the input focus invokes the default button's command handler. No additional code required.

Comment: How do I set the BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON style? Is there a function to do this with?

Comment: @bob There multiple ways to do this: Pass the flag along when dynamically creating the control using `CreateWindow`, add the style in your .rc script if you have a dialog resource, or use the Resource Editor.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to handle the Enter key without dismissing the dialog, you may be going about it incorrectly.  Please take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301409.aspx) MSDN article.  While using PreTranslateMessage should work, it is not the best way to handle these types of events.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the OnKeyDown message, and handle the VK_RETURN character inside that function.

```
void MyCtrl::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags) 
{
    if(nChar == VK_RETURN)  
    {       
        // Do Stuff 
        return; 
    }   

    CWnd::OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```

Comment: Should I still handle it in PreTranslateMessage as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
Another way to overwrite the message.

BOOL CMyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {       
        switch (pMsg->wParam)
        {   
        case VK_RETURN:
            {
               UINT nID = ::GetDlgCtrlID(pMsg->hwnd);       

                if (nID == ID_APPLY)
                { 
                   //DO YOUR STUFF HERE
                }        
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg); 
}
```

Also, you don't need to use PreTranslateMessage if you are using ::OnKeyDown

Comment: Handling the keypress in `PreTranslateMessage` or `OnKeyDown` will fail to display visual cues for the default button. In addition, your suggested implementation will perform **two** actions in response to pressing the Enter key.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I should have specified that once the message is processed return TRUE from the loop (if (nID == ID_APPLY) { //DO YOUR STUFF HERE }). As such I didn't understand about visual cues. Is it the case that if I override then default hint won't be displayed?

Comment: The default button has a distinct visual representation (see *Default command buttons* at [Command Buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511453.aspx)). The dialog manager's default implementation looks for a button with the `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style and provides the visual cue. A custom implementation can implement the `DM_GETDEFID` message handler to report the default button ID. The dialog manager does not analyze the `PreTranslateMessage` implementation to deduce the default button ID.